# Width of a grid column

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, grid-layout

I have a problem with setting a Column width in my grid. That grid is auto-generated inside a button and I don't know the actual width of it nor the width of a window. I have defined two columns in it, one has static width and for the second one I want to be set to all the left place. Problem is that I am generating all those grids and columns just at the moment of running of a program so I'm not able to use the width property of any other object as everything is double.NaN.

What I want to do is generating a button grid containing two columns, one static width and the second which width can change through the time like on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxC1r.png) (the red text is just a comment).

The code I use for generating that grid. The problematic column is the one with width property set to "???" for now:

```
Button GridButton = new Button()
{
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    Margin = new Thickness { Left = 10, Right = 5, Top = 10, Bottom = 10 },
    Height = 70,
    /*HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
      VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
     */
    Tag = GridButtonTag,
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
    Padding = new Thickness { Left = 0, Right = 0, Bottom = 0, Top = 0 }
};

WholeGrid.Children.Add(GridButton);

Grid ButtonContentGrid = new Grid()
{
    Padding = new Thickness { Left = 0, Right = 0, Top = 0, Bottom = 0 },
};

double ColumnWidth = GridButton.Width - 80;

ColumnDefinition Column1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition Column2 = new ColumnDefinition();
Column1.Width = new GridLength(????);
Column2.Width = new GridLength(90);
ButtonContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(Column1);
ButtonContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(Column2);


TextBlock Questions = new TextBlock()
{
    Margin = new Thickness { Right = 0, Top = 0, Bottom = 0 },
    Width = 90,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
    FontSize = 45,
    Text = QuestionsAmount,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right
};

Grid QuestionsGrid = new Grid()
{
    Width = 90,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
};

QuestionsGrid.Children.Add(Questions);

Grid.SetColumn(QuestionsGrid, 1);
ButtonContentGrid.Children.Add(QuestionsGrid);

Grid TwoTexts = new Grid()
{
    Height = 70,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    Width = GridButton.Width - 80,
    Padding = new Thickness { Left = 0, Right = 0, Top = 0, Bottom = 0 }
};

RowDefinition TextRow1 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition TextRow2 = new RowDefinition();
TextRow1.Height = new GridLength(50);
TextRow2.Height = new GridLength(20);
TwoTexts.RowDefinitions.Add(TextRow1);
TwoTexts.RowDefinitions.Add(TextRow2);

TextBlock NameBox = new TextBlock()
{
    Margin = new Thickness { Left = 0, Top = 0},
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    FontSize = 35,
    Text = Name,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
};

TextBlock DescriptionBox = new TextBlock()
{
    Margin = new Thickness { Left = 0, Bottom = -10 },
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    FontSize = 15,
    Text = Description
};

Grid.SetRow(NameBox, 0);
TwoTexts.Children.Add(NameBox);

Grid.SetColumn(DescriptionBox, 1);
TwoTexts.Children.Add(DescriptionBox);

Grid.SetColumn(TwoTexts, 0);
ButtonContentGrid.Children.Add(TwoTexts);

GridButton.Content = ButtonContentGrid;
```

Alternate option - ListView (still the same problem and again the Place With WidthValue="????" is the one I don't know how to set):

```
<ListView Name="FileListView" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="10,10,10,10">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="90" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="92"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                      BorderThickness="0,2"
                      CornerRadius="2"
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      Margin="40,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      />

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="90" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Name ="Texts" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch" Margin ="0" Height = "70" Tag = "{Binding GridButtonTag}" Background ="#00FFFFFF" Padding = "0">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize = "45" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding QuestionsAmount}" />

                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Width="????">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize = "35" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize = "17" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid Name="Buttons" Width ="65" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding = "10,5,10,10" Height = "90" Margin = "0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Tag = "{Binding PlayButtonTag}" Margin = "0" Height = "50" Width = "50" HorizontalAlignment = "Center" HorizontalContentAlignment = "Center" VerticalAlignment = "Top" VerticalContentAlignment = "Center" Background = "#00FFFFFF" Padding = "0">
                                <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/PlayIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Button>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Width="50" Height="20">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Button Grid.Column="0" Tag = "{Binding EditButtonTag}" Margin = "0" Height = "20" Width = "20" HorizontalAlignment = "Left" HorizontalContentAlignment = "Center" VerticalAlignment = "Top" VerticalContentAlignment = "Center" Background = "#00FFFFFF" Padding = "0">
                                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/EditIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin = "0" Tag = "{Binding DeleteButtonTag}" Height = "20" Width = "20" HorizontalAlignment = "Right" HorizontalContentAlignment = "Center" VerticalAlignment = "Top" VerticalContentAlignment = "Center" Background = "#00FFFFFF" Padding = "0">
                                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/DeleteIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The question is what should I change or write in that code to achieve the right result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/1tzBl) This is what I actually get from the code (NOT what I want to get) (the red drawings are what the debugger shows me as the borders od the textboxes inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to set the `Width` you're trying to set. The problem in this case should be that the content of the `DataTemplate` is not stretched at all.

You have to add the following lines to your `ListView` to let the content stretch:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

By the way, I see, you are using Grid with `ColumnDefinitions` or `RowDefinitions` really often in your ListView. This could slow down your UI.. You should consider using [`StackPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel) and [`RelativePanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel) as well as removing some unnecessary Grids.

Comment: What I'm doing is generating interface from the XML file so I can't really use that method and with the star width I have tried this already but it doesn't really work. It's still like the automatic width

Comment: And the button is there to make the grid clickable

Comment: Unfortunately That's still not a thing. The problem still exists even though I have removed the line you mentioned and added star width. I have also changed some align properties but it's still not a solution.

Comment: I have just found the way to achieve what I want but it's rather bug than feature. The trick was to set the width of the Grid inserted to the problematic column to a big number like 10000 and then the right side of it was cut and the rest was like I wanted but it's still not what I want to get (although looks perfect)

Comment: You are setting the HorizontalAlignment of the TwoTexts to Stretch and line after that you are setting the its Width to GridButton.Width - 80. I'm not sure if this causes your problem, but you could try removing the line.

Comment: Also, even when you are generating the UI from XML, there are ways to do that automatically using ObservableCollection (if you have collection of items) and DataTemplates in ListView for example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with ListView, much easier than writing it all in c# though I still have the same problem with width (XAML code is in Question)

Comment: I've updated my answer.. I think that should help you with your problem.

Comment: But will I be able to use those panels with irregular UIs like here? I mean not the table view but here few more columns, there more rows etc

Comment: Of course you will, just take a look at the classes and get to know how they work.